# Mouseleave fires when mouse is inside span

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making this plugin

HTML

```
<span class="item" data-item="first">
</span>
  <br><br>
<span class="item" data-item="second">
</span>
<br><br>
<span class="item" data-item="third">
```

Jquery

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
     $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){  
          var item = $(this).attr('data-item');
          alert(item);           
      });    

    return this.each(function() {    
      for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        $(this).append('<span class="act" title="active '+i+'">act'+i+'</span>');
      }   
    });
  };
})(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').myPlugin();
});
```

The problem is when i hover between two dynamically created elements mouseleave fires even if i'm inside item class.
Demo http://jsbin.com/IWutoQa/9/

Try moving mouse between act1&act2

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ ?

Comment: @mplungjan still firing after stopPropagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the `margin-left: 10px`! Use `padding-left: 10px` instead and it will work properly.

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKc6T/)

Comment: it worked tnx.. but i want to know y the event is firing when i'm inside span

Comment: @Ace You are not inside the span anymore! Margin produces gaps **outside** the actual element; padding **inside**. Look at the [margin example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKc6T/1/). It uses margin (like yours) but with borders. So you can see that there is a gap between the spans (--> the `mouseleve` event is fired). If you compare it with the [padding example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKc6T/2/) (like my solution) you will see that there are no gaps between the spans anymore (--> the `mouseleve` event isn't fired)